# What file type for this logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

A friend of mine is starting his own business and he asked me to edit the logo he already has made, so it can be stretchable (a vector I'm assuming). He says it will be used for a sign. He said whenever they tried it before the logo would become pixelized and distorted.

I turned the logo into a vector but I am not sure what type of file to save it as, I don't know if I should send them just a plain .png, the .ai file itself or something completely different. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What file type should I use for a logo when exporting from Adobe Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28778/what-file-type-should-i-use-for-a-logo-when-exporting-from-adobe-illustrator)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a **vector** file, you want to *keep it vector* as much as possible. A PNG is **not** a vector format, it's raster, i.e. pixels.

You typically want to send a vector format -- .ai, .eps, .pdf

In today's world, a **PDF** saved from Illustrator is a good bet.

Ultimately, if possible, it's best to **ask** the sign maker or check their web site for file requirements.

---

Sidebar... you'll want to *avoid raster effects* within Illustrator as well -- glows, drop shadows, etc. Those are *pixel-based* and their quality **will** decrease if the artwork is enlarged.

Comment: +1, You'll also want to avoid such effects (glows, shadows etc.) in a **logo** - because it's a logo.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using SVG (scalable vector graphic) file format for a logo as resizing is easy and also it won't distort or pixelate.

Comment: Excellent point. +1. Just be aware svg is unsuitable for print production - it's *only* for the web.

Comment: @Scott thank you. Yeah i find .tiff files suitable for print as they are significantly larger than jpeg and can be either uncompressed or compressed using lossless compression.

Comment: Tiffs work. Although if you have an SVG, saving that as PDF or EPS would typically be better `:)`

Comment: @Scott okay i’ll try this next time 

Answer (score -1):

You can save it as EPS.

This would be the general format for vector images using Adobe Illustrator.